# Specify field in an include

Tags: sequelize.js

When you have a table associated with another one on several fields, how do you specify which field you want to use in the include array?

For example, let's say you have a table name "Review" with columns "CreatedBy", "UpdatedBy" and "DeletedBy".

You have 3 associations for that table, one for each "xxxxBy" field and all pointing to the table "User".

Now, you want to query all Reviews that were created by a specific user, how would you do that with Sequelize?

```js
 const Review = sequelize.define('Review', {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.UUID
        },
        text: {
            type: DataTypes.String,
            allowNull: false,
        },      
        createdBy: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        updatedBy: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        deletedBy: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
        },

    }, {});


 const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.UUID
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.String,
            allowNull: false,
        },  
    }, {});


Review.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'createdBy' });
Review.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'updatedBy' });
Review.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'deletedBy' });
```

The query I would do if there was only one field pointing to "User".

```js
Review.findAll({
   include:[{
      required: true,
      model: User,
      where: {
         name: 'xxx'
      }
   }] 
});
```

How do you specify the join is done on "createdBy"?

I guess I could use the following but I was hoping there was a way to say only something like "on: 'createdBy'" or "onField: 'createdBy" etc ...

```js
include.on: {Review.createdBy: User.id}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the association an alias (using AS):

```
Review.belongsTo(User, { as: 'joinCreatedBy', foreignKey: 'createdBy'});
```

Refer to the alias in the findAll:

```
  Review.findAll({    
        include: [
        {
            model: User,
            as: 'joinCreatedBy'
        }]
  ....
```

Give it a try **without** the alias - you should see an error asking you to identify which association to use...

Comment: That males sense! I will try it but I can feel it's the proper way so I've set your reply as the accepted answer. Thanks!